# gradle compile error: could not find symbol

Tags: java

I am compiling a java project and encounted a strange problem,when I build using this command:

```
./gradlew -p web -x test build
```

It throw this error:

```
/Users/dolphin/source/spider-monitor-backend/monitor/data/src/main/java/mapper/SpiderAnalysisMapper.java:5: error: could not find symbol
import model.Page;
```

When I started in Intellij Idea,it works fine!!!!!!!Where is the problem?How to fix it? I already using clean command:`./gradlew clean`.

Gradle version:4.4
Java version:1.8

This is my project:https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/spider-monitor-backend.git

Comment: The message is clear

Comment: Why Intellij Idea could run it smoothly?@Jens

Comment: Because idea does not use the gradle build files for bulding the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should understand what's the difference of compile\implemention\api keywords. implemetion keyword should not expose the class of dependency,so you need replace implemention keywords  with api:

```
api project(':common')
```

and import the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```